# Does the data (Bundle) from navArgs persist after the killing and recreation of the Activity (and Fragment) by the system?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation, android-bundle

*This question has been answered already by Ian Lake, from Google. I was suggested to recreate the question on StackOverflow and answer it myself, so it might help someone else who googles it :)*

When using Navigation API, and SafeArgs:

```
val args: SomeFragmentArgs by navArgs()
```

Does the `args` field keep its values after the activity gets killed by the system and recreated?
In other words: does the Bundle sent to the Fragment survive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer given to me by Ian Lake (from Google):

> The Bundle of arguments sent to a Fragment are indeed part of the
> Fragment's saved instance state. There's no reason to store it again
> separately

So indeed, it does survive.